How to reset MySQL connection in Node.js
I'm running a small MySQL database locally on my computer for a personal project. To make entering data easier, I wrote up a bare-bones website interface. Everything works fine, the data gets put in the database, it can update entries, etc. However, the Node web server only sends 6 queries. After 6, it just stops sending anything.
Thus far, I've worked around it by restarting the node server after every 6 entries. However, that (obviously) gets annoying very fast.
Is there a way to refresh the connection or increase the number of queries allowed?
After some research, I learned about mysql.createPool() which, after replacing .createConnection(), I still only can do 6 queries.
I've also had the thought of closing the connection (when I was using .createConnection()) and then reconnecting.
The only other potential I can come up with is that the problem is on the database side, where it only allows 6 queries per connection or something. (and restarting the node classifies as a new connection)
Node.js DB code
const mysql = require("mysql2");

// Database Connection
var con = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    database: "....",
    user: "....",
    port: ....,
    password: "...."
});

// Only used with mysql.createConnection()
// con.connect((err) => {
//  if(err) throw err;
//  console.log("Database Connected");
// })

app.post("/input", (req,res) => {
    if(req.body.code) {
        addToDatabase(....);
    } else {
        addToDatabase(....);
    }

function addToDatabase(...., variant = "") {
    // Check for existing entries
    con.query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id_inventory = '"+....,

        function (err,result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result.length > 0) {// If there is a matching entry
                con.query("UPDATE....",

                    function (err2, result2) {
                        if(err2) throw err2;
                        console.log("UPDATE....");
                    });
            }
            else {// If no matching entry is found
                if(variant == "") {// If no variant
                    con.query("INSERT INTO inventory....",
                        
                        function (err, result) {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            console.log("INSERT....");
                    });
                }
                else {// If there is a variant
                    con.query("INSERT INTO inventory....",
                        
                        function (err, result) {
                            if(err) throw err;
                            console.log("INSERT....");
                    });
                }
            }
    });
}


Share the code inside addToDatabase. My guess is that you're grabbing a connection from the pool but not releasing it but the code you shared doesn't show this.

@Evert Shouldn't .query() do that automatically?

It should if you query directly on the pool! But not if you start a transaction or reserve a connection with getConnection. Doesn't seem like that's the case here so still strange

Yeah, I was using mysql.getConnection() before, so my variable is called con. As a part of testing a few things out, I just switched the method to mysql.createPool() but didn't change the variable name to pool like I probably should've. So, I'm sure that's probably a little confusing...
